# Exchange FSA K-Force Light chainset with a SRAM RED

Tags: bottom-bracket

I'm the lucky owner of a  Fuji SST 1.0 from 2010 (mounted with a Shimano press-fit bottom bracket). I would like to exchange the front chainset from a FSA K-force 53/39 to a SRAM RED 50/34. Can you help me to what bottom bracket I need to purchase and get fitted?

Comment: You might want to double-check since I'm not 100% but I think maybe your current bb will be ok. I have a Shimano press-fit bb and am happily running Hollowtech 2 cranks. I'd make sure on the sram site. Note that press fit bb's are a pita - special tool to remove, another special tool to insert. Each tool costs more than the bb itself.

Comment: Thanks PeteH, when trying to fit it, the fit is fine, but the SRAM's starshaped end (sorry, I don't know how else to explain it) is 1cm longer, which makes the BB unstable. Thanks Frank

Comment: star-shaped = splined. But unfortunately that's my limit! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the GXP Red cranks (more normal) you want a [Pressfit GXP Bottom Bracket](https://www.sram.com/truvativ/products/truvativ-pressfit-gxp-bb).

If you have the BB30 Red cranks you want a [Pressfit 30 BB](https://www.sram.com/truvativ/technologies/pressfit-30)

**However** not all press fit systems are created equal. I would have your LBS check compatibility, and supply and fit a suitable part.

SRAM make both of these in the whole range of series from Red down to non-series Truvativ-branded versions.